# Problemas para colocar un vídeo en HTML

Tags: html, html5, visual-studio

Estoy empezando a aprender HTML. El problema que me da el código es que inserto el vídeo a como se debe, es decir, de esta manera:

```
<video src="video.mp4">Lo sentimos, este vídeo no puede ser reproducido en tu navegador</video>
```

Sin embargo, cuando actualizo el documento HTML no me aparece el vídeo y estoy perdido porque se supone que la línea de código está bien.

Ya verifiqué varias veces la ubicación del fichero para ver si estaba bien. Hasta lo cambié de ubicación para que fuese *más fácil de ubicar*. Utilizo Visual Studio.

Comment: Hola @LuisEdwards ¿para qué agregas el mensaje de "Este video no puede ser reproducido en tu navegador"?

Comment: Hola @RichardCruzAmbrosio, solamente lo hago por si se da el caso que el navegador en el que se busque esta "página" no admita o por cuestiones de conexión no cargue bien el vídeo, es decir, es como un mensaje de Try-catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema puede deberse a que no encuentra el vídeo y puedes averiguarlo dando clic derecho sobre la página y elegir *Inspeccionar elemento*.

En el conjunto de pestañas, entras en *consola* y si el mensaje de error que te dispara es parecido a **URI no válida**, significa que no estás accediendo correctamente al fichero en cuestión.

Comment: Tienes razón me aparece que no se encuentra el vídeo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregar el vídeo de esta forma:

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Lo sentimos este vídeo no puede ser reproducido en tu navegador.
</video>
```

Puedes cambiar el width a la anchura en pixeles que quieres que tenga tu vídeo.

Comment: Ahora se me agregó el marco del vídeo, pero no me muestra el vídeo :/, no se que pasa

Comment: Podría ser la ruta del vídeo, prueba con /video.mp4 o si el vídeo está en una carpeta mas arriba, ../video.mp4, y tambien prueba en otro navegador.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :(, gracias por tu ayuda igual